# Absolute div inside Relative Div with slide up transition

Tags: css

I am trying to create a display of an element.

The element needs to have an image and an overlay (which contains text). The overlay on hover needs to have a slide up transition on hover. I have achieved this.

But the problem is that the overlay div goes beyond the image div. While it should appear exactly inside of it.

I am using Bootstrap.

The Div in blue should not go beyond the image left and right boundaries and also should be visible when not hovered only 50px. While hovered, the remaining content should be visible.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="main-container">
            <img class="image" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97300&w=350&h=300">
            <div class="content">
              Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment.

    Bring to the table win-win survival strategies to ensure proactive domination. At the end of the day, going forward, a new normal that has evolved from generation X is on the runway heading towards a streamlined cloud solution. User generated content in real-time will have multiple touchpoints for offshoring.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS Code:

```
/* Set to 100% of col-md-6 */
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
/* Image Container */
.main-container > img.image {
  position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 100;
}
/* Overlay */
.main-container > .content {
  width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: -110px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.8);
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
/* Overlay Hover */
.main-container > .content:hover {
  bottom: 0px;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/j02mwxwn/)

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer, so I can adjust and you accept.

Comment: the blue background div is visible out side the image. i want it to actually be visible completely only when hovered. and for people to know that there is some text in it, i need to keep it a little above the image bottom. hence thought the height of the blue div is 150px I have shifted it only -110px below.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j02mwxwn/2/ ... also updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `position: absolute`, which will position itself relatively to the first parent that also have a position set (other than `static`), and as you want it to relate to the `.main-container`, add `position: relative;` to its rule

*Updated based on a comment*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j02mwxwn/2/)

```
.main-container {
  position: relative;             /*  added property  */
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;               /*  added property  */
}
```